# How to use ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB (converting byte[] yuv to byte[] rgba)

Tags: android, renderscript

I have `byte[] yuvByteArray` (540x360 image captured from `Camera.PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame` method and dumped into `assets/yuv.bin` file). I want to convert `byte[] yuv` to `byte[] rgba` array, using the following code (based on LivePreview android example).

But I receive `outBytes` rgba array filled with zeros after forEach and copying `out` allocation to outBytes. What's wrong with my code?

---

```
package hellorender;        
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Element;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Type;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import hellorender.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class HelloRenderActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int W = 540;
    public static final int H = 360;
    private RenderScript rs;
    private ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB yuvToRgbIntrinsic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AssetManager assets = getAssets();
        byte[] yuvByteArray = new byte[291600];
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[W * H * 4];

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = assets.open("yuv.bin");
            System.out.println("read: " + is.read(yuvByteArray));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        rs = RenderScript.create(this);
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs));


        Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
                .setX(W).setY(H)
                .setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
        Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);


        Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs))
                .setX(W).setY(H);
        Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        in.copyFrom(yuvByteArray);

        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);

        out.copyTo(outBytes);

        Bitmap bmpout = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        out.copyTo(bmpout);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bmpout);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that `ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB` is set for a video color space (a.k.a. BT.601), while camera preview comes with the Jpeg (full) range of colors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yuv.bin file is definitely in NV21 format, as it captures here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame

setYuvFormat method is from API level 18, I removed it

So this code works fine:

```
rs = RenderScript.create(this);
yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(yuvByteArray.length);
Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(W).setY(H);
Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

in.copyFrom(yuvByteArray);

yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);
```

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working.  Unfortunately, the intrinsics and most of RenderScript isn't well documented so it's easy to have strange things like this.

Comment: How do we get the converted RGB byte array?

Comment: This is crazy fast compared to having the rutine done in pure java !!

Answer (score 4):

Using API18+ **wilddev**´s answer can be slightly improved as you don´t need Type.Builder objects.
Do all this stuff in the onCreate() method:

```
aIn = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.U8(rs), H*W*3/2); // what the f**k ?  This is 12 bit per pixel, giving the length of the camera data byte array !

bmpout = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // you will need this bitmap for output anyway

aOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bmpout);  // tada !

// and set the script´s input
yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(aIn);

// as pixel data are stored as int (one byte for red, green, blue, alpha), you first need an int[] array
int rgba[] = new int[w*h];   // the rgba[] array
```

Now you can continue with *these* lines **or** put them into the onPreviewFrame() method:

```
aIn.copyFrom(data);  // or aIn.copyFromUnchecked(data);  // which is faster and safe for camera data

yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(aOut);  // execute the script

aOut.copyTo(bmpout);  // copy result from aOut to bmpout

// if you need the rgba-values, do
bmpout.getPixels(rgba, 0, W, 0, 0, W, H);

// now you may loop through the rgba[] array and extraxt the r,g,b,a values 
// and put them into a byte[] array(s), BUT this will surely have impact on the performance when doing in Java
```

Answer (score 3):

Our internal test app uses the following sequence to create the YUV allocation.

```
    tb = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.createPixel(mRS, 
              Element.DataType.UNSIGNED_8, Element.DataKind.PIXEL_YUV));
    tb.setX(mWidth);
    tb.setY(mHeight);
    tb.setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
    mAllocationIn = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, tb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

Then inside the callback that new YUV data is available do

```
    mAllocationIn.copyFrom(theYuvByteArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Kotlin

```
        val rs = RenderScript.create(CONTEXT_HERE)
        val yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))

        val yuvType = Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(byteArray.size)
        val inData = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)

        val rgbaType = Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(width).setY(height)
        val outData = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)

        inData.copyFrom(byteArray)

        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(inData)
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(outData)

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        outData.copyTo(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your output type passed to the constructor of `ScriptIntrinsicYubToRGB` to be `Element.U8_4` instead of `Element.RGBA_8888`.  You'll need the same for the `Type.Builder` used to create the output `Allocation`.

Comment: outBytes filled with zeros again.

Comment: And there is a crash 

     Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Allocation kind is USER, type UNSIGNED_8 of 4 bytes, passed bitmap was ARGB_8888

after `out.copyTo(bmpout);`

Comment: Change the `.setYuvFormat` to use `android.graphics.ImageFormat.YV21` rather than `android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21`, unless your raw binary is multi-plan YUV.  In that case use `android.graphics.ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` instead.

Comment: Also, you don't want to call `out.copyTo(bmpout)`, you'll want to call `bmpout = BitmapCreateBitmap(outBytes, W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`

Comment: YV21 results in zeros again. YUV_420_888 crashed with android.support.v8.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Only NV21 and YV12 are supported..

Comment: :-)  Typo on my part.  YV12 is what you want.  NV21 isn't YUV, it is YCrCb.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42432/discussion-between-wilddev-and-larry-schiefer)