# image manipulation as byte[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

I'm sorry that I'm not good at English.

I want to make a real-time image manipulation app.`(Binarization, color inverse...etc.)`

It needs speed, so I want to manipulate it as `byte[]`, without converting to  `Image` or `Bitmap`.

The format of image that I got from camera was `YUV(NV21)`, but because I don't know about this format, I convert it to JPEG.

but it also doesn't work as I expected.(I thought it would be one byte per one pixel or three byte per one pixel.)

So,

1. How can I do such `manipulation(binarization, color inverse)` as JPEG byte array?
2. or How can I convert NV21 format byte array to RGB byte array?

and I used the method to convert `NV21` to `JPEG`.

```
YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, outputStream);
```

and I got `yuv` image byte array from `onPreviewFrame(Camra.PreviewCallback)`.

Comment: +my device doesn't support RGB format, so i have to convert it.

Comment: These links might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276522/convert-nv21-byte-array-into-bitmap-readable-format
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb

Comment: One question per question, please.  Both 1 and 2 here should be separate.  In addition, you'd need to define what manipulation() is supposed to do, its too vague right now.  Furthermore, it would be unusual to work on JPEG directly-  its compressed data.  You usually turn it into a bitmap and work on that.  And you'd never use JPEG as an intermediate format because its lossy-  you'd use PNG if anything.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. I'm not used to here yet.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Your best bet is to work with ColorMatrices. You can do Greyscale conversion, Invert, Sepia (or other colors) toning, Brightness/contrast adjustment, Binarization, .... this kind of "filters". Very quickly. And easily. No need for 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use setPreviewFormat(int) to set other than the default NV21 format for camera captures.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21

Comment: yes, i tried it. but my device doesn't support RGB format, so i have to convert it.