# Byte array into the greyscale. Android take photo

Tags: java, android, colors, camera, image-thresholding

When I am making photo in android I receive a byte array from camera. I would like to convert this array(image) into the 2 colors - white and black. Any ideas? Changing camera mode to mono/negative is not a sollution for me.

Greetings.

EDIT1: Code is in Java

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create bitmap from your array:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
// data is your byte array
Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpOriginal);
Bitmap bmpGrayscale = toGrayscale(bmpOriginal);
bmpOriginal.recycle(); // free memory immediately, as your bitmap is not garbage collected by now.
```

Then, you can pass your `bmpOriginal`, which is colored image, to converting method

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal) {        
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

Above code will give you grayscale bitmap. It simply applies zero saturation filter to image. As the saturation is the purity of a color, the less purity - the less color difference. After applying above filter the only difference you get is brightness. The brightest is white, the darkest - black. If you want to convert it back to byte array you can try something like this:

```
Bitmap bmpGrayscale = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmpGrayscale.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
bmpGrayscale.recycle(); // free memory immediately, as your bitmap is not garbage collected by now.
```

Comment: Unfortunately Bitmap factory always return a null

Comment: @CallMePedro I think this question can help you with converting NV21 to preferable format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276522/convert-nv21-byte-array-into-bitmap-readable-format

Comment: Yep I checked this but there is no way back to byte array. It is saved as IMG and thats it. After all conversions still i need back to previous byte format cause of scanning this byte array as image of qr code

Comment: @CallMePedro actually, top answer shows how you can use it to create bitmap object. You can then obtain bytes from bitmap probably

Comment: yes you was right. However this soultion gave me bitmap in only one green color. But at least I am moving forward :)