# Android an NDK method has a reentrancy issue

Tags: android, optimization, android-ndk, redundancy, reentrancy

This is my NDK method:

```
 void FrameReceived(int width, int height, const char *rawImageBytes, int size, jboolean remote)
{
//LOGE(".... **** ....FrameReceived Begin = %d", size);

if(size == 0)
    return;

jboolean isAttached;
JNIEnv *env;
jint jParticipant;
jint jWidth;
jint jHeight;
jbyteArray jRawImageBytes;

env = getJniEnv(&isAttached);

if (env == NULL)
    goto FAIL0;
//LOGE(".... **** ....TRYING TO FIND CALLBACK");
LOGI("FrameReceived will reach here 1");
char *modifiedRawImageBytes = malloc(size);
memcpy(modifiedRawImageBytes, rawImageBytes, size);
jint sizeWH = width * height;
jint quarter = sizeWH/4;
jint v0 = sizeWH + quarter;
for (int u = sizeWH, v = v0, o = sizeWH; u < v0; u++, v++, o += 2) {
        modifiedRawImageBytes[o] = rawImageBytes[v]; // For NV21, V first
        modifiedRawImageBytes[o + 1] = rawImageBytes[u]; // For NV21, U second
}

if(remote)
{
    if(frameReceivedRemoteMethod == NULL)
        frameReceivedRemoteMethod = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedRemoteCallback", "(III[B)V");

    if (frameReceivedRemoteMethod == NULL) {
        //LOGE(".... **** ....CALLBACK NOT FOUND");
        goto FAIL1;
    }
}
else
{
    if(frameReceivedMethod == NULL)
        frameReceivedMethod = getApplicationJniMethodId(env, applicationJniObj, "vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedCallback", "(III[B)V");

    if (frameReceivedMethod == NULL) {
        //LOGE(".... **** ....CALLBACK NOT FOUND");
        goto FAIL1;
    }
}

jWidth = width;
jHeight = height;

jRawImageBytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, size);
(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, jRawImageBytes, 0, size, modifiedRawImageBytes);

//LOGE(".... **** ....CALLBACK BEING CALLED");
if(remote)
{
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, frameReceivedRemoteMethod, 0, jWidth, jHeight, jRawImageBytes);
}
else
{
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, applicationJniObj, frameReceivedMethod, 0, jWidth, jHeight, jRawImageBytes);
}
//LOGE(".... **** ....CALLBACK CALLED");

(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jRawImageBytes);
free(modifiedRawImageBytes);

if (isAttached)
{
    (*global_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(global_vm);
}
//LOGE("FrameReceived End");
return;
FAIL1:
if (isAttached)
{
    (*global_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(global_vm);
}
FAIL0:
//LOGE("FrameReceived FAILED");
return;
}
```

Which calls, based on the jboolean remote, 1 of this 2 functions:

```
 public void vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedCallback(final int participantId, final int width, final int height, final byte[] rawImageBytes) {
    if (selfView == null || selfView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        return;
    try {
        selfBitmap = Nv21Image.nv21ToBitmap(rs, rawImageBytes, width, height);
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                selfView.setImageBitmap(selfBitmap);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("Error on vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedCallback: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
public void vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedRemoteCallback(final int participantId, final int width, final int height, final byte[] rawImageBytes) {
    if (remoteView == null || remoteView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        return;
    try {
        remoteResolution = width + "x" + height;
        remoteBitmap = Nv21Image.nv21ToBitmap(rs, rawImageBytes, width, height);
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                remoteView.setImageBitmap(remoteBitmap);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("Error on vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedRemoteCallback: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you can see, this 2 functions look the same, having just the imageview and the bitmap where I save the data, different.
but if I profile my app.

The first method when it calls, it's thread looks like this:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/A3lm3QTz4gZN0VK/upload.png
And it's average time is 4 seconds, for 15 seconds of profiling.

BUT the second methond, the remote one, does this:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/wHp7NtKgKYTTEG7/upload.png
And the time is 15seconds out of 15.

Here you can cleary see, that somehow it being redundantly recalled:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/wCmS5CH21zbyMBr/upload.png

Why is this happening?

## Edit:

I modified the remote function to simply do this:

```
public void vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedRemoteCallback(final int participantId, final int width, final int height, final byte[] rawImageBytes) {
    Log.i("", "vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedRemoteCallback RECEIVED FRAME ");
}
```

And by profiling that thread, I get this:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/ZfylnBheyA6GjTe/upload.png

I think something in the NDK is causing the function to somehow be recalled multiple times

Comment: well, one difference could be that the video resolution is not the same for selfView and remoteView. Please note that [I warned you that setImageBitmap() is too slow for live video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996722/i-need-to-create-a-bitmap-in-c-code-in-ndk#comment87014505_49996722).

Comment: That is true, but for some reason I get with renderscript better performance than from my openGL code. and I profiled both, and for both I get the remote code called 4 times instead of once. 
PS: The resolution is smaller than the self view

Comment: The first question I'd ask is why yuvToRgb is shown to call itself.

Comment: That's where I am also lost. I am editing my question now, to include more data

Comment: Your interpretation of the profiler results is incorrect. Sure the callback is triggered for every received frame, but the profiler shows only Java methods.

Comment: I added some logs in the NDK code, and it's not being called at a higher rate than the vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedCallback. But I don't get, even for the Log inside my function, why does it get called multiple times. Also what is the code regarding the ThreadGroup and Refference, that is what gets called from the NDK I am assuming?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170135/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-rosu-alin).