# YUV to RGB conversion with OpenCV for Android camera

Tags: opencv, colors, android-camera, yuv

If I understand correctly, when I use OpenCV to convert YUV to RGB using the `cvtColor(CV_YUV420sp2BGR)` function I actually call [`YUV420sp2RGB888Invoker`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L4274) class.

The conversion formula is

```
R = 1.164(Y - 16) + 1.596(V - 128)
G = 1.164(Y - 16) - 0.813(V - 128) - 0.391(U - 128)
B = 1.164(Y - 16) + 2.018(U - 128)
```

These coefficients apply to [CCIR 601 spec](http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html) where the ranges of **Y**, **U** and **V** are respectively `[16 … 235]`, `[16 … 240]` and `[16 … 240]`.

But the Android camera (specifically, on Snapdragon) seems to return the NV21 image in full (JFIF) range of `[0 … 255]` for all components (See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702836/192373).

*Is there a way to use OpenCV color conversion for the JFIF color range?*

Comment: There's a lot of [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+%5Bandroid%5D+yuv). Have you tried them?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @[karlphillip](http://stackoverflow.com/users/176769/karlphillip). I definitely read most of these entire, and even had answered some of them. I even link to one of them. But I have not found one that concerns my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

According to this OpenCV documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html

The transform **CV_YCrCb2BGR** seems to be what you're looking for. It uses the same coefficients that are mentioned in the stackoverflow answer you linked (full range with 1.403, 0.714, 0.344 and 1.773).

Comment: Thanks, but if I am not missing something, this transform assumes 420 planar, not NV21 semi-planar format.

Comment: @Alex Cohn hi, have you by any chance, managed to figure it out? 

Android's camera image preview output holds 3 planes,which the Y is not twice the resolution of U and V in both dimensions, therefore I couldn't use the approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230188/yuv420-to-bgr-image-from-pixel-pointers

Comment: @JammingThebBits You are welcome to look at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348#issuecomment-675728428

Comment: Thank you @AlexCohn , I appreciate it!!