# NV21 format and odd image dimensions

Tags: android, image, android-camera, yuv, nv12-nv21

I have been working for some time with NV21 images in Android and I have been tracking a bug that might be caused by incorrect indexing bytes in an NV21 image.

The image in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272388/extract-black-and-white-image-from-android-cameras-nv21-format) has a nice overview of how the Y, U and V bytes are positioned in the image buffer.  Not sure it is allowed, but I am embedding it below:

[image: YUV420SP NV21 format]

1. What happens when the image has odd dimensions (as in parity)? Is that even possible in this format?
2. Do we have an official specification of this format somewhere?

Comment: The graphics was wrong, showing NV12 format. I have updated the graphics (I also commented the problem in the referred answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of an image with odd dimensions (i.e one of W or H, in a WxH image is odd), you'd expect the Y plane to be fully sampled as always, with WxH samples, followed by 2(⌈W/2⌉ x ⌈H/2⌉) chroma samples, where we divide each image dimension by 2 but round up rather than round down.

So some of the pixels at the very edge of the image have chroma samples that correspond to only 1 or 2 original pixels, rather than 4. I hope that makes sense. You can see in this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24148) that a couple of other libraries have had issues handling odd dimensions in YUV images previously.

For your second question, I haven't seen an official specification, but I have seen some code in the android framework that handles this format, I will see if I can dig up a link to it, and append it to this answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer already, but if you can come up with that link it would be really nice to illustrate the "official" format.

Comment: @silvaren [`Yuv420SpToJpegEncoder::deinterleave`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.4/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/YuvToJpegEncoder.cpp#deinterleave) may be what you're looking for, for full stack trace see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36560663/253468

Comment: @silvaren notice that they just `width >> 1` in the C++ code, because Android's `YuvImage` does not support odd-sized images, see [`YuvImage.adjustRectangle`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-mr2.2-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/YuvImage.java#L214).