# Confusion regarding the image format NV21 and the different memory layouts it seems to have

Tags: android, image-processing, yuv, image-formats, nv12-nv21

I have to deal with images in the format given above. However, I have found conflicting information about it.

According to [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272388/extract-black-and-white-image-from-android-cameras-nv21-format) the UV values follow eachother, while according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) the V values lie AFTER the U values in memory. Which one is correct, or if they both are, what is the difference?

Could it be a NV12 vs NV21 problem? However, [this](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php) site states that they should simply be switched.

Maybe it has something to do with the image being planar, semi-planar or not planar, though I have no idea what these terms mean.

Can someone clarify this a bit?

Answer (score 1):

For NV21, the order is V/U. The [Wikipedia description of NV21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420sp_(NV21)_to_RGB_conversion_(Android)) is correct.

The diagram in the [StackOverflow response you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702836/100633) has an error. A couple people in the comments pointed this out.