# I try to create a bitmap from a YUV Image, but the image looks distorted (has green and pink overlay)

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, imageview, yuv

This is the function that I use:

```
public void vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedCallback(final int participantId, final int width, final int height, final byte[] rawImageBytes) {
    if (selfView == null || selfView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        return;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(rawImageBytes, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width / 2, height / 2), 50, out);
        byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
        final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                selfView.setImageBitmap(image);
                System.gc();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.info("Error on vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedCallback: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is being called from a Video SDK which sends the byte array.
I have also tried this function: convertYUV420_NV21toRGB8888
from the following link: [Extract black and white image from android camera's NV21 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272388/extract-black-and-white-image-from-android-cameras-nv21-format/12702836#12702836)
And both times this is the image that I get back:

[image]

What could go wrong here?

## EDIT:

I also tried with renderscript:

```
try {
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[W * H * 4];
        rs = RenderScript.create(getActivity());
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs));


        Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
                .setX(W).setY(H)
                .setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
        Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);


        Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs))
                .setX(W).setY(H);
        Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        in.copyFrom(rawImageBytes);

        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);

        out.copyTo(outBytes);

        final Bitmap bmpout = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        out.copyTo(bmpout);

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                remoteView.setImageBitmap(bmpout);
                System.gc();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.info("Error on vidyoConferenceFrameReceivedRemoteCallback: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

But the same. How can I know that the bite array I get from the camera is valid?

I also included a file here, that shows the byte array I receive:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbubwpx06ypr61e/byte%20array.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you attached is very low quality 320x180 [I420](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-i420/).

Comment: you are reffering to the bytearray? Thanks

Comment: How can I try to create the I420 picture? YuvImage says it only supports NV21 and YUY2

Comment: Thanks a lot, after I knew the format, I used this to change it to NV21, and then I used the YUVImage class: https://gist.github.com/pnemonic78/2d8411ed6b0bd6c71b651800bc97eb8e